# How to display ACF field after the product name on the cart and order reviews in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, woocommerce-theming

I have Advanced Custom Fields setup for post type on WooCommerce Products. So each product has 1 unique custom field.

I'm trying to display the custom field after the product name on the cart and the checkout page and order table information.

However, running into problems as my code doesn't display any output.

Any advice on how to achieve this would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
// Display the ACF custom field 'location' after the product title on cart / checkout page.
function cart_item_custom_feild( $cart_item ) {
    $address = get_field( 'location', $cart_item['product_id'] );
    echo "<div>Address: $address.</div>";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'cart_item_custom_feild', 10, 1 );
```

I also tried `the_field` instead of `get_field`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### 1- On the cart page AND on the order review table on the checkout page

If you would need to run it both on the cart page **AND** order review table on the checkout page, you could use `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter hook, like this:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'order_review_custom_field', 999, 3);

function order_review_custom_field($product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
    $address = get_field('location', $cart_item['product_id']);

    return ($address) ?
        $product_name . '<div>Address: ' . $address . '</div>'
        :
        $product_name . '<div>Address: No address found!</div>';

}
```

Here's the result on the **cart page**:

[image]

And on the **order review table on the check out page**:

[image]

---

##### 2- On the email AND in the order details table on the thank you page:

We could use `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` action hook to append the custom field value to the end of product name on the email template:

```php
add_action("woocommerce_order_item_meta_end", "email_order_custom_field", 999, 4);

function email_order_custom_field($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text)
{
    $address = get_field('location', $item->get_product_id());

    echo ($address) ?
        '<div>Address: ' . $address . '</div>'
        :
        '<div>Address: No address found!</div>';
};
```

And here's the result on the email:

[image]

And in the order details table on the thank you page:

[image]

---

This answer has been fully tested on woocommerce `5.7.1` and works.

Comment: Thank you Ruvee. Wondering would it also be possible on order table in WooCommerce Orders? wc-order. do_action -> 'woocommerce_email_order_details',

Comment: Which order table?  Order table on the email template? Or order table on the admin dashboard?

Comment: The Order table on the email template.

Comment: I've added a snippet for the email as well.